# How to create Webservice with extension .aspx and how to use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webmethod, pagemethods

I have to send and get a response from a webservice ending with .aspx.   I used HTTP post method. Is it the best way? How do I wait for a webservice response?  To send and and get a response I am using the following code. But I am unable to test it, as I do not have the webservice.

```
WebRequest _request = WebRequest.Create("https://somewebsite.com/webservices/XMLInbound.aspx");
_request.Method = "POST";
XElement xele = new XElement("RAFeed");//Substitute here with XML File that is created with all the parameters
byte[] bytearray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xele.ToString());
_request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
_request.ContentLength = bytearray.Length;
_request.Timeout = 5000;// Here i wait for the response is the correct way ?
//Gets the request as a stream
Stream datastream = _request.GetRequestStream();
datastream.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
datastream.Close();

//Gets Response

WebResponse response = _request.GetResponse();
//// Display the status.
//Debug.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);          

datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();//Response is in this string            
reader.Close();
datastream.Close();
response.Close();

var Rdoc = new XmlDocument();
Rdoc.LoadXml(responseFromServer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont create web services with .aspx extensions. You create static web methods inside a aspx page. Such web methods are called **Page methods**. They are created when you dont want to expose your web methods as a service.

If this is not what you want, go for a web service- WCF or ASMX.

Page methods example : http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: yes i have to call a webmethod in a ASP.Net page in a windows application I tried webrequest Post method but it is returning the complete html of the page. how do i call it?

Comment: Is there any specific reason, you are using page methods, instead you can use a asmx service right?

Comment: i am working on a task where i have to send data over a webservice which ends with .aspx so i wrote a code which is here above, but i do not have any to thing to test it.